# Running SSIS Solution/Package deletes components out of the Data Flow Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I'm working on a package to import data from a raw text file to a table in SQL Server. My package contains:

1) An Execute Process Task that runs a batch file to compile .txt files

2) An Execute SQL Task that Truncates the table I want to import

3) A Data Flow Task that takes the data from the raw text file and puts it in the table in SQL Server

I was able to run each step individually and they worked as expected - however, when I run the solution from inside SSIS itself, it gives me the "success" message but nothing actually happens. Even worse, the components of the data flow task are now missing.

Has anyone experienced this who found a work around?

Comment: What does this mean:   "when I run the solution from inside SSIS itself"?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the package control flow?

Comment: I have never experience that behavior in 13+ years of building SSIS packages. I think we're going to need more detail as the other folks have indicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the lack of specifics! I actually figured it out. Let me clarify my second paragraph:

The batch portion and the Execute SQL Task work perfectly when I disable the Data Flow Task! However, upon enabling the Data Flow Task, the package would "run" but not complete the Data Flow Task and would delete the Data Flow Task's components completely. Within the data flow task I had:

1) Flat File Source

2) Conditional split that ignored rows in the first column if the value was "".

3) OLE DB destination table

What I found is that changing the Conditional Split from specifically ignoring rows with "" to making the criteria based on value length, rather than looking for that symbol, worked out and didn't completely delete out components in the data flow task.

TL;DR: For whatever reason, the solution I built didn't like the conditional split criteria being based on the "" character. When I removed that, the solution worked perfectly.